# Using setAllowedOrigins on WebSocketHandlerRegistration not allowing CORS with localhost

Tags: websocket, cors

I have setup a websocket server in Spring which uses a WebSocketConfig as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(webSocketHandler(), "/websocket").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
    @Bean
    public WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler() {
        return new ServerWebSocketHandler();
    }
}
```

My setup entails establishing a websocket connection with the server from a website. The website is running locally (e.g. http://localhost:5555) and is using the [Websocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket). I am able to establish a connection and send/receive messages only if `setAllowedOrigins("*")`. I have tried, for example:

- `setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:5555")`
- `setAllowedOrigins("http://127.0.0.1")`
- etc...

However, only `"*"` allows the connection be established. How can I narrow the allowed CORS origins?